# how to create an xml using java?

Tags: java, xml

i am new for XML.i have a function that takes four input.on the basis of these four parameter create an XML using Java.for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<validateemail>
<emailid>xyz@gmail.com</emailid>
<address>abc,street</address>
</validateemail>
```

After that formed XML is return as String.please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of generating XML: DOM, SAX, JAXP. I prefer DOM over e'thing because of its' simplicity. You can try this link: http://genedavis.com/library/xml/java_dom_xml_creation.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should go through some tutorial related to this.  [This](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html) is the first one that I found in google search.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in XML APIs in Java can be a bit of a pain. You may want to use something like [JDOM](http://jdom.org) instead (or any of the many other APIs available). There are various tutorials available, including [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdom/) which covers quite a bit of the API simply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing the final xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"> 
<validateemail> 
 <emailid>xyz@gmail.com</emailid> 
 <address>abc,street</address> 
 </validateemail>
```

instead of directing you towards the APIs, here is something to just get you started:
you would have to use StringBuilder object.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">");
```

then add the parameters accordingly,

```
sb.AppendLine("<validateemail>");
sb.AppendLine("<emailid>"+emailidvalue+"</emailid>");
```

The same can be done for other parameters as well.
This is only a rough idea for the problem. how you implement it is strictly upto you.

Comment: make sure you escape the " characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java DOM API, it's the easiest way. ["Link"](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/blackwood/dom/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how I did this, Tell me if it's help :) ?

'
**ValidateEmail entitie**

```
public class ValidateEmail {

    private String emailId;
    private String address;

    public ValidateEmail(){}

    public ValidateEmail(String emailId, String address) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.address = address;
    }

    //Getters / Setters
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}


**MyXMLMaker**

package com.isi.lf.myXMLMaker;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import com.isi.lf.entities.ValidateEmail;

public final class myXMLMaker {

    public static Document getXMLDocumentFromValidateEmail(ValidateEmail ve){

        Document doc = null;

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            doc.setXmlVersion("1.0");
            doc.setXmlStandalone(true);


            //Generate the XML doc
            Element root = doc.createElement("validateemail");

            Element emailid = doc.createElement("emailid");
            emailid.setTextContent(ve.getEmailId());
            root.appendChild(emailid);

            Element address = doc.createElement("address");
            address.setTextContent(ve.getAddress());
            root.appendChild(address);

            doc.appendChild(root);


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return doc;
    } 
}

**The main for the output test**

package com.isi.lf.myMain;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import com.isi.lf.entities.ValidateEmail;
import com.isi.lf.myXMLMaker.myXMLMaker;

public class MyMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = myXMLMaker.getXMLDocumentFromValidateEmail(new ValidateEmail("admin@admin.com", "Montréal Canada"));

System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeName()+" : "+doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeName()+" : "+doc.getChildNodes().item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
}
}
```

'